# How to convert html numeric character references to chars?

Tags: php, html

I have this: `[ &#171;&#187; ]` how i can convert it to `[ «» ]`?
Is there a php function for this?

Comment: `html_entity_decode` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: How is `&#171;&#187;` equivalent to `""` or you meant this `«»` ?

Comment: Yes. sorry. My mistake. «»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't understand if your values need to be in array or not,

If they are just variables you could do this:

```
<?php
$from = "&#171;&#187;";
$to = html_entity_decode($from);
print($to);
```